# requirejs lost prototype due to variable scoping?

Tags: javascript, scope, prototype, require

I'm trying to develop (re-write) as small chess engine (2 players on tablet, or remote gaming)

since properties and bahaviour appear gradually on the system when growing the nubzer of types available : i m making some intermediate modules between

- basic ones : camps, algebraic-references, windrose
- intermediate : chessmen, board, tiles
- global ones : the game

I"m using require.js to define my modules, I have a lot of objects cross references, so I m building a pool (transaction manager) to hold relationship across the dependencies graph.

the problem comes when trying to get the prototype of one object outside of the module it was defined, like this :

```
// file: js/app/chess/board.js
define("chess/algebr", function(algebr) {
    var Board = function(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // other stuff ...

    return {
        create : function() { return new Board(); }
    }
});

// file js/app/colorchess.js
define("core/pool", "chess/board", "chess/tile", function(pool, board, tile) {
    // some other stuff...

    var board = board.create();

    console.log(board.prototype); // --> undefined

});
```

So, what's wrong ?
Where board's prototype has gone ?
Is it a story of scoping between modules ?

Regards.

Comment: `var board = board.create();` why are you redelcaring it?

Comment: var board : the variable itself, board.create the module, better if called "boards" since it's a (collection) type definition ! (mistake #2)

Answer (score 0):

***This has nothing to do with require.js.***

`prototype` is just a property you are mistakingly trying to access, confusing it with *prototype* setter:

```
var Board = function(id) {
    this.id = id;
};

Board.prototype.test = function () {return 42;}

console.log( (new Board()).prototype );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gtb2L/

Compare with:

```
console.log( (new Board()).__proto__ ); // works in fresh browsers like Chrome 30, IE11
```

in this you *will* see the reference to internal *prototype*

Comment: effectively I'd mistaken... by doing obj.constructor.prototype.propXYZ I can access the internal prototype (since __proto__ is not really cross browser) ! Thanks for help.